# Retrieving Google+ Auto-Backup Images via Python

Tags: python, google-data-api

I've spent all morning trying to track down a way to get access to my Google+ Auto-Backup photos programmatically. The most promising is the [Picasa Web Albums API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python), but I can't work out how to get authentication working (which I would need to get access to my private photos).

The example on the [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python#AuthSub) page doesn't work because the `gdata.photos.service` doesn't appear to be in the `google-api-python-client` package anymore.

Any ideas for how to attack this?

Answer (score -1):

I've found a script from [PicasaDeleter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PicasaDeleter), and the authentication looks working well. But I can't get access to the Aotu_Backup photos, It seems that you can only get access to the PUBLIC albums while the Auto Backup is a folder instead of an album and all albums in that folder are PRIVATE.
I am a newbie, maybe I've been misunderstand the situation.